# How is position differentiable?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, physics

Consider this graph of some point's position vector's endpoint - a function of time - on a Cartesian plane:[image]
This is a perfectly normal path - after all, in real world there is nothing keeping point from taking a sharp turn like this. However, in mathematical physics, we consider position vector as a differentiable function, where $\dfrac{df(t)}{dt}=(\dfrac{df_x(t)}{dt},\dfrac{df_y(t)}{dt},\dfrac{df_z(t)}{dt})$.

In the graph I posted, the component $f_x$ seems to be undifferentiable at point $f_x(t)$, since there its goes through a cusp.

Is there something I'm not seeing and there is a derivative of $f_x$ at $t$, or is this point really undifferentiable?

And if it is, why do we define position vector as a differentiable function?

Comment: well at the sharp turn the gradient is undefined, same as a sharp turn in a graph like f(x) = |2x+5|

Comment: Physically one expects finite acceleration, in which case the velocity vector is continuous and the position vector is differentiable.

Comment: @mjqxxxx Or, if you don’t want infinite acceleration, the body must come to a stop at the corner in order to change direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the function $f_x$ is not differentiable at that corner point, unless the particle (or whatever it is) stops at the point.
Consider the trajectory $t\mapsto(t^3,|t|^3)$.
It makes a sharp turn but the function is differentiable everywhere.
But this is only possible if the particle stops at the corner.

Why do you define position vector as a differentiable function, then?
You shouldn't.
Typically piecewise differentiable is reasonable for physical problems:
the particle travels along nice differentiable trajectories, but there can be sharp turns where differentiability fails.

There is also a way to define the derivative of $f_x$ in your example, but it would not be a function.
It would be a distribution.
This generalization is not always useful, though, and it can be technically more confusing than just working with piecewise smooth trajectories.